# resizing window and keeping div in same place

Tags: html, css

I have currently having issues keeping my div in the same place when the window is resized. In the example, it is .add div. The issue I am having is that it is going above the view region of the page, and I can't scroll to that portion of the page so I can't even see that when I resize.

Here is the code.
http://jsbin.com/kazizeruxi/1/

This is the part that I have tried dealing with

```
<div class = "add" align = "center">
<!--Everything inbetween -->
</div>
```

Ideally I am trying to keep the entry (in the farthest up left) to stay in the upper left no matter how it is resized.
I have tried messing around with media queries, but to no avail. It just turned out to be very inefficient with different browser sizes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Connor did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just give them a `absolute position`.

```
.add {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do that is to give your element the `position : fixed` then it will have a fixed position from the root element or the body not the parent.

let us say you want it to be centered on the screen you can use this

```
.add{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)
}
```

of if you have a fixed with and height you can use margin instead of transform

```
.add{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50% 0 0 -50%
}
```

if you give it an `position: absolute` and the parent has a `position: relaive` then it will move with the parent element on resize